# Python CSV - Dynamic number of rows based on a variable

Tags: python, csv, variables, header, row

I'm trying to write a CSV file, which contains lists with lengths that vary dynamically depending on a user's data input. I'm OK with printing the lists but I also need to put a header row at the top, that should look something like:

Generation:, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, (etc - counting up the number of generations.)

I have a variable for the number of generations that is set by the user, this is called numGens() - can I use this to help write the correct number of headings?
The first field must be "Generation:" Followed by the right number of generations counting up.

Sorry if I've repeated myself! Thanks.

EDIT - added the relevant code!

```
def exportData():
    #naming and namecheck here
    with open('testthing.csv','w', newline='') as csvfile:
            spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                                    quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            spamwriter.writerow(["Generation:",])
            spamwriter.writerow(["Juveniles:", juvOverGens])
            spamwriter.writerow(["Adults:", juvOverGens])
            spamwriter.writerow(["Seniles", juvOverGens])
```

juvOverGens (and there are meant to be different names for the Adults and Seniles but that's irrelevant because they would always be the same length) is a list that is anywhere between 5 and 25 values in length.

Comment: Please add the code you think is relevant for us helping you come closer to your problems solution - this is often simpler, than describing it in words ;-)

Comment: Sorry. Added it now.

Comment: Can you also show a sample of the sort of data you're talking about, and how this header row relates to the format?

Comment: As in, post a snippet of the CSV? Sorry - I'm all new to this.

Comment: Would this work for you? `spamwriter.writerow(["Generation:", [i+1 for i in range(len(juvOverGens))]])`

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

numGens = 4

header = ['Generation:']

for n in range(numGens):
    header.append(str(n + 1))

with open('testthing.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(header)
```

Comment: I've just tested that and I get the following error: line 89, in exportData
    for n in range(numGens):
TypeError: 'function' object cannot be interpreted as an integer